# Why use a concept of free will in reasoning if it's unproven?

Tags: free-will

The concept of free will is indeed to much religious reasoning, yet its existence is still unproven. Using an unsubstantiated assumption to prove other conclusions is problematic from a logic perspective. A few key issues with relying on free will in religious arguments:

- There is no scientific consensus that free will, as commonly conceived, actually exists. Deterministic neuroscience and psychology suggest behavior is shaped by biology, genetics, and environment - not an independent "soul".
- Asserting free will exists because we subjectively feel we have it is questionable. Our perceptions are imperfect and biased. We also lack choice in what we perceive and feel.
- Even a logical/deductive proof of free will would not necessarily prove it aligns with religious notions of a soul. The exact mechanism and nature of free will requires further definition.
- Using free will to justify religious doctrines of sin, punishment, reward etc. is circular if free will itself stems from religious assumptions. It presumes the conclusion.

My question is - how can you prove anything using an unproven assumption as a tool of a proof?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147422/discussion-on-question-by-serg-z-why-use-a-concept-of-free-will-in-reasoning-if); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: There's nothing about "free will" that requires an "immortal soul"; and indeed it's perfectly coherent to believe in an "immortal soul" without believing in "free will". So the premise for your question seems to be flawed from the start.

Answer (score 6):

**Any and all** logical arguments start with unfounded premises. What's needed for rigor is keeping your premises clear and, if it isn't obvious in context, conditioning your conclusions upon the premises from which they are derived. It is the *explicit*, not the *unassailable* premise which provides rigor. Your own reasoning expressed in the comments works like this.

> If we accept the concept of free will as a given without proof

1: Suppose (in spite of obvious evidence to the contrary) that we have accepted the concept of free will

> it opens the door to accepting other unproven assumptions.

2: This indicates that we accept at least some principles without evidence.

> This could lead to logical inconsistency...

3: Some principles accepted without evidence are inconsistent with measurement or with one another.

> and the erosion of rigorous, evidence-based thinking.

4: Therefore 1 implies we may not retain rigorous, evidence-based thinking.

---

> Using free will to justify religious doctrines of sin, punishment,
> reward etc. is circular if free will itself stems from religious
> assumptions. It presumes the conclusion.

This is only the case if free will stems from religious assumptions *about* sin, punishment, and reward. Generally the operating premise in scripture-oriented religions is something like "the holy book is true, at least insofar as it operates as a guide for how to think and act", and the belief in free will is derived by trivial textual analysis.

Comment: Your argument hinges on the acceptance of free will as a given, but I must stress that this is not a universally accepted premise. Numerous philosophers, scientists, and thinkers have contested the concept of free will, arguing instead that our actions are determined by a complex interplay of genetic and environmental factors.

Moreover, even if we grant the premise of free will, it does not automatically legitimize other unproven assumptions, as you suggest. One must still apply rigorous, evidence-based thinking to each new assumption or proposition.

Comment: The acceptance of free will does not give us a license to abandon critical thinking and blindly accept unfounded premises.

As for your final point, the circularity persists even if free will is derived from religious text rather than stemming from assumptions about sin, punishment, and reward. If the religious text is used as the basis for the concept of free will, and then free will is used to justify the doctrines of sin, punishment, and reward that are found in that same text, we are still presuming the conclusion.

Comment: [it does not automatically legitimize other unproven assumptions, as you suggest]
I neither granted the premise of free will nor suggested any such legitimization. I did note that *you* granted the (counterfactual) premise that you believe in free will and showed how you used an unsupported premise to make your point.

Comment: [If the religious text is used as the basis for the concept of free will, and then free will is used to justify the doctrines of sin, punishment, and reward that are found in that same text, we are still presuming the conclusion.] I'm not going to respond to this since you already know that I disagree and I'm not here to argue. However, I encourage you to try to apply the principle to things that aren't emotionally loaded, like, say, building codes, auto repair manuals, or the plots of romance novels. I believe you will discover the error eventually.

Comment: [The only way to break this circularity is to establish the validity of the religious text independently of the concepts it espouses.] This is correct, although I wouldn't use that phrasing. (I would say something like: "the only way to establish whether X makes true claims is to measure reality and find out whether or not the measurements comport with the predictions made by X").

Comment: If you think all (or any) your logical arguments start with unfounded premises, then I'm very skeptical of your ability to make good arguments. If you don't have a good justification for believing something, you absolutely shouldn't be using it as a premise to conclude some other belief about reality. Of course we can have complete certainty about almost nothing, but that doesn't mean all our premises are "unfounded". Simply having "clear" premises doesn't say anything about whether they correspond in any way to what's actually true.

Comment: Quite correct, which is why we measure as well as argue - although the validity of measurement itself and in general  is an unfounded premise until separately defended, whereupon we remove to yet some other unfounded premise like the utility of the senses, in defense of which one can only note circularly that it seems to our senses that all those who credibly doubted the premise died as a consequence of not believing their sensory apprehension of the necessity and availability of food and drink, and avoiding high energy collisions.

Comment: @gs The utility of the senses is that (1) it leads to a seemingly coherent model of reality, and you needn't know whether this model is real to effect this model, (2) the model being real would be accepted under Occam's razor - the model must exist in some form, even if imagined, so if it's not real, there must be *more*, (3) not acting as if the model is real leads to pain, which, regardless of how "real" it is, creates an unpleasant experience for us, and I, for one, would rather avoid that (similarly, this may also lead to depriving ourselves of joy, which I would prefer to experience).

Answer (score 5):

Your question embeds several invalid assumptions, which I will try to pull out and identify for you, as learning about them will assist you in your philosophical development.

1. You presume that philosophy requires foundationalism -- the building up of a philosophic worldview from unquestionable starting points.  The most famous foundationalist was Descartes, who noted our inability to question our experience and selfhood and reasoning ability.  Descartes effort to build up a worldview from there -- was then assisted by a more questionable assumption of a benevolent God whose benevolence justified our faith in our intuitive knowledge.  Without that more suspect step, foundationalism does not really get off the ground. There is so little that one can establish based on this limited set, that it leads to a nearly useless worldview.  AND -- multiple philosophers have even challenged Descartes very limited set of unquestionables -- including selfhood, experience, rationality, and consciousness.  None of these are actually "unquestionable".  Foundationalism is both flawed in its concept, and would be useless in application if we could implement it.
2. Rationalism -- you are presuming a rationalist worldview -- that one can establish reality based on reasoning.  This was challenged by Kant, who pointed out that pretty much all of science was contingent -- it could have been otherwise.  Hence rationalism is inapplicable to science, and more generally to all empirical subjects.  Rationalism also falls afoul of the Munchausen Trilemma:  [Is the Münchhausen trilemma really a trilemma?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64638/is-the-m%c3%bcnchhausen-trilemma-really-a-trilemma/64646#64646)  It has also run afoul of the inability of logic systems to be complete, per Godel, and of the infinite number of different logics.
3. Motivated reasoning.  You have an objective, to attack religion.  Motivated reasoning has been shown in multiple studies to drive people to accept bad arguments and rationalizations in order to justify the conclusion they want to reach.

Alternatives to rationalism include:

- Coherentism -- make a collection of assumptions, see if they cohere into a valid combo of principles, and produce a useful worldview.  This is the alternative approach adopted by many philosophers.  Coherentism does not arrive at just one possible conclusion -- there can in principle be multiple simultaneous coherent proposals.  Coherentism has been criticized by empiricists as -- impossible to achieve.  Science is not coherent today, and the majority of philosophers of science think it is not possible to make it coherent, ever.
- Pragmatic empiricism -- accept that "Truth" is only ever approximate, and that we have to live with reasonable approximations to truth and knowledge, rather than any certainties or coherencies.

Under coherentism, the difficulty you identify for defining free will -- would prohibit including free will in a coherent worldview.  At least some of your critiques of free will would remain under that alternative.

Under pragmatic empiricism, observations are king, and free will is observed.  Our inability to develop a full and coherent theory uniting our observations of the world -- is seemingly insurmountable, and would not be an objection to free will thinking.

The supposed empirical evidence against free will you assert, however, would be an obstacle.  However, that deterministic objection is generally based on bad science, see: [The Mediocrity Principle, The Laws of Nature and Free Will](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95603/the-mediocrity-principle-the-laws-of-nature-and-free-will/95606#95606) for one set of citations against either a physics or logic based anti-free-will argument, and [‘Libet’s delay’ and the philosophy of mind and free will](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/88568/libet-s-delay-and-the-philosophy-of-mind-and-free-will/88570#88570) for a repudiation of the standard determinist interpretation of Libet type experiments.

Using free will as a reasonably well supported reality in religious reasoning would be fine in a pragmatic empiricist worldview, provided one accepts the evidence against the determinist rejection of free will.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147430/discussion-on-answer-by-dcleve-why-use-a-concept-of-free-will-in-reasoning-if-it); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

It's not disproven either. When you examine philosophical discussions of free will, you find the pivotal issue is, defining your terms. And, it is basically impossible to get the different groups to agree to define the same terms in the same way.

I like Nietzsche's analysis in Beyond Good & Evil.

> "The desire for "freedom of will" in the superlative, metaphysical
> sense, such as still holds sway, unfortunately, in the minds of the
> half-educated, the desire to bear the entire and ultimate
> responsibility for one's actions oneself, and to absolve God, the
> world, ancestors, chance, and society therefrom, involves nothing less
> than to be precisely this causa sui, and, with more than Munchausen
> daring, to pull oneself up into existence by the hair, out of the
> slough of nothingness."

And he concludes

> "The 'un-free will' is mythology; in real life it is only a question
> of stronger and weaker will."

The existence of gravity limiting our choices does not make us unfree. And the same for all the laws of physics. Because freedom is an experience not a fact, it is the experience of choice-making, in the face of our limited knowledge of the world, and of what the consequences of our choice will be. We know perfectly well that some people are slaves to their impulses, while others have developed skills to avoid cognitive biases, conditioning by experience, and coercion. We have a term for being relatively more free, and it is embedded in the core of the origin of philosophy, the term is wisdom. I describe it as the lived practice of finding the integrated centre of our concerns, towards developing the skill of solving dilemmas, here: [Wisdom and John Vervaeke's awakening from the meaning crises?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82325/wisdom-and-john-vervaekes-awakening-from-the-meaning-crises/82333#82333)

No one argues that our freedom to act in the world is unlimited. But Sartre says:

> "Man is condemned to be free; because once thrown into the world, he
> is responsible for everything he does."
>
> -from his essay Existentialism and Human Emotions

This is in the sense that, we can imagine different futures from different actions, and so decide what kind of person we want to be and what kind of life we will live, based on what consequences we expect. It doesn't matter what physics says. We experience choice-making, and imagine consequences, and to pretend otherwise is to live in Sartre's Bad Faith.

I would caution those bent on a Determinist denial of free will, that 'predictable in principle' is a mirage. All the computing power on Earth can barely keep track of the quantum states in piece of matter the size of a tennis ball. And we know from quantum mechanics and relativity, that what information can be transmitted about one piece of matter to another, and what cannot, has real substantial consequences. Sequences of random quantum events rapidly become impossible to keep track of and predict, even with all the material of the known universe directed to such a task. So in what sense is such a prediction, part of our universe?

And yet, heuristics like character, might make pretty good predictions of a system too complex for our entire universe to keep track of. Like, a human building a nanomachine that could turn our galaxy into copies of the nanomachine all engaged in a computation. Physics alone cannot be used to determine the future of our universe, from within it. We have to accept other heuristic explanatory layers like 'intentions', where agents make choices, because they have a great deal of explanatory power to account for events which physics conducted in our universe cannot.

Comment: Your discourse is indeed well-articulated and reverberates with echoes of eminent thinkers. However, we must tread carefully. The problem of free will is not merely a semantic one. It's not just about how we define our terms, but about how we reconcile our subjective experience of free will with the objective reality of a deterministic universe.

Nietzsche's notion of a 'stronger and weaker will' is indeed intriguing, but it doesn't necessarily settle the question of whether our will is truly 'free'

Comment: The fact that some people are more susceptible to their impulses than others could just as easily be explained by deterministic factors such as genetics, environment, and upbringing.

The assertion that freedom is an 'experience' rather than a 'fact' raises another issue. Our subjective experiences are not always reliable indicators of objective reality. There are countless examples of cognitive biases and perceptual illusions that demonstrate this. So, the experience of choice-making does not necessarily prove the existence of free will.

Comment: Now, to Jean-Paul Sartre's existentialist argument: while it is indeed empowering to believe that we are 'condemned to be free' and responsible for our actions, this doesn't establish the existence of free will on a metaphysical level. It is more of a moral stance than an empirical claim.

As for the limitations of determinism, I agree that our current scientific models cannot predict every single event in the universe. Quantum mechanics, in particular, introduces a level of randomness and uncertainty.

Comment: However, this doesn't necessarily imply free will. It simply means that there are limits to what we can predict.

Finally, the usefulness of concepts such as 'intentions' in explaining human behavior does not imply that they are fundamental realities. They could still be emergent properties of a deterministic system. Just because we find certain concepts useful or necessary for our day-to-day functioning does not mean they are metaphysically real.

Comment: @SergZ.: The only way a quantum universe can be deterministic, is across Many Worlds, or Superdeterminism where an 'outside' perspective to the universe is required & *within the universe it's not deterministic*. 'Free' is a spook, a causa sui imagining a disconnect is possible from the past, & from present conditions; & you are refusing to be shewed from a linguistic bottle. You have the choice, whether to be conditioned by a past of incoherent philosophy, or understand & accept the basis of your own freedom in relation to the dilemmas you face.

Comment: We unjustifiably elide 'predictable in principle', the validity of Laplace's Demon's perspective, & possible in the world. Q mechanics shows us that if we can't distinguish between states without altering them, then there is a degree of uncertainty that cannot be eliminated; & that has real physical consequences. I like the idea of 'teleonomic matter', coined by Krakauer, & discussed in this Mindscape episode: https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/podcast/2023/07/10/242-david-krakauer-on-complexity-agency-and-information I'd relate that to intersubjectivity, Indra's Bet, & peer-to-peer reality

Answer (score 2):

You seem to subscribe to an invalid definition of free will. There should be no question whether free will exists or not. All valid definitions make it clear whether we are talking about a real or an imaginary thing.

One of the best definitions is "the ability to make decisions". We do have this ability, naturally. This definition makes sense in both religious and non-religious contexts.

We can choose what we do and we are responsible for our actions. To God, to other people, to the society.

Comment: I read your question on meta re. downvoting, and thought it fair I comment here. I think this is the first time I've downvoted one of your questions and I didn't comment because our discussions (while polite) never seem to be productive. The reason I downvoted here was your claim, "We do have this ability, naturally". This is a highly controversial claim, yet you provide no reasoning for your confidence. Many professional philosophers who claim we have no free will would claim that our experience of making decisions is illusory, so it's wrong to simply write this view off without explanation.

Comment: When you contradict a significant viewpoint, it's important to at least acknowledge that your view is controversial rather than claim your opinion as fact. If the experts in the field acknowledge we cannot prove the issue of free will one way or the other, what special access to information do you have that they don't? If you do have access to such information, it would make for a relatively famous philosophical contribution at the moment, because you're claiming to have solved a question most agree is currently unsolvable. And doing this doesn't help anyone here. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I don't want to represent my views as anyone else's but it wouldn't surprise me if the reason you keep getting downvoted is because you are prone to making assertions without providing supporting evidence, in a similar way to the way you have in this answer. I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @Futilitarian There is no controversy about our ability to make decisions. It is a proven fact that we can perform voluntary actions that, unlike involuntary actions, are *not* mere causal reactions to past events. We do decided things that serve a purpose, attempt to achieve a goal in the future. The only way this could be an illusion is to assume that we are remotely controlled puppets under someone else's control. We have no reason to assume that. There is no indication of any kind of puppet master.

Comment: This is what I mean. It is _not_ a proven fact. And, contrary to your claim, the only alternative to free will is _not) that we are under someone's control. These are very basic mistakes that lead to your comments being downvoted. It's not a personal issue.

Comment: @Futilitarian Besides, the illusion idea (not even a theory) explains nothing. It doesn't matter if we are human beings discussing or puppet masters discussing through our human avatars.

Comment: Again. Wrong. The idea of illusionism explains a lot. The notion that the world is partly deterministic and partly random suggests we have no free will. There is no evidence that I am aware of that supports the idea that we originate ideas, divorced from typical cause and effect. It _may_ be the case that we have free will, but no-one has been able to provide evidence for it, other than the experiential.

Comment: @Futilitarian Please note, that I am not talking about free will, I am talking about the ability to make decisions, which is only one of the many definitions for free will. Those philosophers who claim or believe something about free will have none. Any valid definition should define clearly whether it is a real or an imaginary thing.

Comment: @Futilitarian Back to decisions. It is a verified fact that decisions are made and someone must make each of them. An illusion means that we experience something else than what happens in reality. When we observe ourselves or others making decisions, what is happening in reality according to these illusionists?

Comment: Again, you are asserting as fact something that is controversial in the literature, by people that are far more qualified than you or I. According to the 'illusionists' what we experience as decisions are merely the determined/random consequences of physical events. If you believe that it is certain that we make decisions, the onus is upon you to explain how you know this. So far you have not done so.

Comment: @Futilitarian I have no obligation to observe the opinions of your imaginary friends. A decision is a deliberate selection of a course of action to serve a purpose. A decision is not a physical event. A decision is an answer to a question, a solution to a problem. A decision could not possibly be a consequence to a physical event.  This is all common knowledge, not anyone's opinion or theory. You know this, too. Someone has to decide what you write here and you are the only suspect.

Comment: "Imaginary friends"? Like Nietzsche, Einstein, Darwin, Schopenhauer, Hossenfelder, Freud and Strawson? These are just a few of course, and you are no obligation to agree with them, but a good answer acknowledges that free will is controversial. Comments like your last one are probably good examples of why people have stopped bothering to comment when they downvote your responses.  There's no need to be disparaging, especially when someone has taken the trouble to respond to your concern about downvoting.

Comment: @Futilitarian They were imaginary until you mentioned their names. My favourite of them is Schopenhauer with whom I share my understanding of free will. None of them denies our ability to make decisions. That would be downright absurd. Those who deny free will are denying something else.

Comment: "*Thought presents alternatives. It was not meant to solve problems or decide things.*" - Zulaikha Mahmoud

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you do not give any definition of free will, as has been told to you in several answers and comments. The answer obviously depends on the definition of free will.

If you define free will as your ability to choose without knowing beforehand what will you choose, then, no matter how predetermined your choice will be by biology, environment or genetics, it may still exist. Even if everybody else knows what you will choose and only you don't know it, you still have free will.

If on the other hand you define it as ability to make choices which are absolutely unpredictable, then precisely religious beliefs contradict it. For, if you believe that there are subjects placed outside of time, able to observe your future directly, then for them the very notion of prediction loses any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that there is no such thing as free will. Then we might ask why we use the concept. Answer: we might use the concept because we lack free will, but are forced to act as if it existed; in order to disbelieve in free will, we would need to choose the believe, i.e., we would need free will.

A shorter answer is just that it is a non-question.

Comment: So, if everyone thinks the same thing, then effectively we are ants: we don't have free will. Does everyone think the same thing? Hmm. We could still say that thoughts vary based on prior conditions: Joe and I think differently about something because 5 minutes ago we were in different spots. My definition of free will is that *I could have chosen otherwise*. The only way to test it is if I do indeed make different choices in similar situations and can give reasons why. We could ask why evolution gave us the ability to give explanations after the fact when we can't in fact choose.

Comment: @ScottRowe I don't know about you, but I had only two legs (last time I counted), which would make me a poor sort of ant. I'm not taking a position on whether or not we have free will; I am responding to the OP's question, by arguing that _either_ free will exists, _or_ it is a necessary fiction: the legal system could not function without an _assumption that there is free will;_ whether or not there is free will, or whether to concept makes sense, is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: And fish, clearly, have not evolved legs yet. So the legal system needs to be involved. :-)

Comment: You don't choose your beliefs, you either are or are not convinced by the evidence. And you seem to be equating the philosophical concept of free will with the ability to make any choice whatsoever, which just isn't what that is (although the philosophical concept of free will is kind of ill-defined and incoherent to begin with).

Comment: @NotThatGuy Thanks for your humble opinion. Not everyone would agree with you, for example [Kierkegaard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_of_faith), but what would he know?

Comment: @SimonCrase I'm not sure how the "leap of faith" Wikipedia article disagrees with what I said. Can you choose to believe that if you go outside, you'll float off into space? I expect not, because we can't choose our beliefs. But the more important part of my comment was about how you're talking about will instead of free will.

Comment: @NotThatGuy There are plenty of people who ignore evidence and choose to believe nonsense, such at Flat Earthers. Your example of someone believing that they will float into space if they go outside is only marginally sillier than extreme agoraphobia.

Comment: @SimonCrase But can you choose to believe that? I also wouldn't say flat Earthers chose to believe what they believe. At most, they chose to engage or not engage with certain things, and be more or less open-minded about what certain people say, and spend more or less time questioning certain parts of what they believe. These can all inform beliefs, but you don't choose the actual beliefs. (And I wouldn't call often-debilitating mental illness "silly".)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not religious and I don't accept that free will exists, so take my answer on how free will factors into religious reasoning with a grain of salt.

- Free will has a strong emotional attachment because we don't just want to be bound to some inevitable destiny based on our biology and environment. We want to be *free*. (This also factors into religious beliefs, because if we don't have free will, it's questionable for a god to punish or reward us for how we act.) But... that doesn't really make sense to me. We are biological creatures. It's difficult to deny that we make decisions based on our biology and environment. And if I'm doing the things I most want to do, that I believe would bring me the most joy and meaning and satisfaction, does it really matter if this is ultimately just a product of my biology and environment? It doesn't seem so.

  To me, this seems like a case of believing something due to emotional appeal, rather than it actually being the most reasonable conclusion based on the evidence.
- There is no scientific consensus that free will, as commonly conceived, actually exists. But there is also no scientific consensus (nor arguably scientific evidence) that a "soul" exists, or that God exists, so this problem isn't really specific to free will.

  Theists commonly argue that religion is outside the domain of science (even if some make dubious claims that science proves God). While atheists argue that science (possibly in addition to maths and logic) is really the only reliable tool we have for gaining knowledge about reality, and if a god does anything in reality (that would make their existence relevant to us), then we should be able to detect it with science.
- Yes, asserting free will exists because we subjectively feel we have it is questionable. Our perceptions are imperfect and biased. (I also don't really know what people feel that gives them that impression, or what exactly this "free will" thing is that they're getting an impression of, because, if anything, I feel rather bound to my desires and the limitations of my mind, which tells me that free will *doesn't* exist.)

  This, again, is not unique to free will. It's similarly a problem for the bulk of spiritual experiences, theology, and just a whole lot of religion as a whole.

  I would consider this to be one of the biggest problems for many religious beliefs. All I've really seen as a rebuttal is that these experiences are more than just feelings, but I haven't seen this claim be substantiated.
- I haven't seen anyone try to conclude free will from logical arguments, or from religious assumptions (even if the belief that we are somehow above the laws of nature can subconsciously be tied to religious beliefs in many cases).
- There is an additional, significant free-will-related problem that God supposedly already knows everything we'll do, and also created us the way we are, and also then punishes us for all of eternity for acting in line with how he created us. So he created us knowing he'll punish us for all of eternity, and he created us anyway... and he's supposedly all-loving.

  This represents more of a problem of internal consistency for religious beliefs.

  Some may also say that you wouldn't actually have free will in this case, but I wouldn't subscribe to that.

  But of course this only represents one particular set of religious beliefs (albeit a common set), while there are many possible religious beliefs.

Comment: Could you please define what free will "as commonly conceived" means to you? Why do you think it's a matter of belief? Doesn't the definition make it clear whether it's a real phenomenon or an imaginary one?

Comment: Self-mastery allows you to be free of your tendencies and desires. Since few people attain it, that is what is missing from the picture provided by religion and science. "*And then a miracle occurs*" is at that spot on the whiteboard. You could look in to self-mastery, to see if it seems valid, and perhaps worth pursuing. My warning is that actually something else happens before you can 'achieve' it.

Comment: I still love your answer.